# expression has 16 elements; expected 17 elements

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

Vivado keeps notifying me about this issue of a mismatch between the two values at `address <= address & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1))`, but I've checked and I shouldn't have an off-by-one error. 
I don't try to access to `address` in any of the other lines of code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...

architecture behavioral of p1 is

    ...

    signal heading_bit                  :   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal heading_counter              :   integer range 0 to 2 := 0;
    signal address                      :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal address_counter              :   integer range 0 to 16 := 0;

begin process(i_clk, i_rst)

       ...
                
                    if(i_start = '1' and heading_counter < 2) then
                    
                        if(i_w = '1') then
                            heading_bit <= heading_bit(heading_counter) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1));
                        else
                            heading_bit <= heading_bit(heading_counter) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 1));
                        end if;

                        heading_counter <= heading_counter + 1;
                        
                    elsif(i_start = '1' and heading_counter >= 2) then
                    
                        if(i_w = '1' and address_counter < 16) then
                            address <= address & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1));
                        elsif(i_w = '0' and address_counter < 16) then
                            address <= address & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 1));
                        end if;
                        
                        ...
            
    end process;
```

I've already looked for previous queries about the same issue and then checked my code again, but I can't seem to find my source of the problem.

Comment: You increase address by 1 bit when using the & operator. Then you try to assign this result with the increased number of bits to address, which has the original number of bits. That is not allowed.

Comment: then why can i do that with heading_bit? do i need to index address as well? or can i just initialize the address vector to all 0s and then change the desired digit by using an index? anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: my aim is to just append the value of i_w to address

Comment: Your provided code isn't valid VHDL, can't reproduce your error and isn't minimal. Provide a [mcve]. Assignment element matching failure occurs either when simulating a model or during synthesis. Note you take an element of heading_bit in assignments to heading_bit and in a cumbersome fashion concatenate a "1" or "0" (and could have been '1' or '0'). In assignments to address you are concatenating the entire address with a "1" or "0" which will result in expressions with more elements than address.

Comment: You don't demonstrate how the i_w appended address is used. Do you need two different names for the shorter address and the one used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side (LHS) and the right hand side (RHS) of an assignment needs to have the same number of bits.

You ask why this works for `heading_bit`. The assignment is:

```vhdl
        heading_bit <= heading_bit(heading_counter) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1)); -- or (0, 1)
```

By indexing a single bit of `heading_bit` and concatenating it with the one-bit `std_logic_vector` the RHS is 2 bits wide. And the LHS is `heading_bit` that is 2 bits wide, too. Everything is fine, syntactically.

But for this assignment you get an error:

```vhdl
        address <= address & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1)); -- or (0, 1)
```

Of course, because you append one bit to `address` on the RHS and then assign this to `address` on the LHS. The widths do not match.

---

Let's assume, that you want to left-shift the bits in `address` and shift in the one-bit `std_logic_vector` on the right. Then the solution is to index the appropriate part of `address`:

```vhdl
        address <= address(15 downto 1) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1)); -- or (0, 1)
```

---

> Would initializing address to a vector of zeroes and then replace a certain digit with either '1' or '0' based on the value of the counter be equivalent as well?

For this you "just" need to translate your statement into this assignment:

```vhdl
        address(heading_counter) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 1)); -- or (0, 1)
```

Comment: would initializing address to a vector of zeros and then replace a certain digit with either '1' or '0' based on the value of the counter be equivalent as well? still, thank you for your answer! it has solved my issue